# F# alternate constructor assigning values to (mutable) let bindings

Tags: f#, constructor

Suppose I have this class:

```
type Pet (name:string) as this =
    let mutable age = 5
    let mutable animal = "dog"
```

I want to be able to create a new `Pet` based on some serialized data, which I represent with this record:

```
type PetData = {
    name : string
    age : int
    animal : string
}
```

(TLDR: I can't figure out the syntax to make a constructor that'll take a `PetData` to populate the let bindings. My various attempts follow.)

So I make a new `Pet` constructor that'll assign values to the let bindings. I try using the class initializer syntax:

```
new (data:PetData) =
    Pet(name,
        age = data.age,
        animal = data.animal
    )
```

Hmm, nope: `No accessible member or object constructor named 'Pet' takes 1 arguments. The named argument 'age' doesn't correspond to any argument or settable return property for any overload.`

I check to make sure I've got all the syntax: no missing commas, correct "assignment" (*cough*) operator, correct indentation.

Okay the, I'll try the record initializer syntax.

```
new (data:PetData) =
    {
        name = data.name;
        age = data.age;
        animal = data.name
    }
```

Error: `The type 'Pet' does not contain a field 'name'`

Okay, so I need to call the main constructor. I guess there are probably two places I can put it, so let's try both:

```
new (data:PetData) =
    {
        Pet(data.name);
        age = data.age;
        animal = data.name
    }
```

Nope: `Invalid object, sequence or record expression`

```
new (data:PetData) =
    Pet(data.name)
    {
        age = data.age;
        animal = data.name
    }
```

And nope: `This is not a valid object construction expression. Explicit object constructors must either call an alternate constructor or initialize all fields of the object and specify a call to a super class constructor.`

I didn't want to have to do this, but maybe since the fields are mutable anyway, I can just assign values to the object after initializing it:

```
new (data:PetData) =
    let p = Pet(data.name)
    p.age <- data.age
    p.animal <- data.animal
    p
```

`Type constraint mismatch. The type      Pet     is not compatible with type     PetData     The type 'Pet' is not compatible with the type 'PetData'`

Lol, what??

Okay, let's try this:

```
let assign(data:PetData) =
    this.age <- data.age
    this.animal <- data.animal

new (data:PetData) =
    let p = Pet(data.name)
    p.assign(data)
    p
```

`The field, constructor or member 'assign' is not defined`

Right, so it can't access let bindings from outside.

Let's try a member then:

```
new (data:PetData) =
    let p = Pet(data.name)
    p.Assign(data)
    p

member x.Assign(data:PetData) =
    this.age <- data.age
    this.animal <- data.animal
```

`This is not a valid object construction expression. Explicit object constructors must either call an alternate constructor or initialize all fields of the object and specify a call to a super class constructor.`

Okay... let's try this whole thing differently then, using explicit fields:

```
type Pet =
    [<DefaultValue>]val mutable private age : int
    [<DefaultValue>]val mutable private animal : string
    val private name : string

    new(name:string) =
        { name = name }

    new(data:PetData) =
        {
            name = data.name;
            age = data.age;
            animal = data.animal
        }
```

`Extraneous fields have been given values`

And that's when I punch my elderly cat in the face.

Any other ideas? These error messages are throwing me off. I can't even find half of them on Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this.

```
type Pet =
    val mutable private age : int
    val mutable private animal : string
    val private name : string

    new (name:string) =
        { 
            name = name;
            age = 5; // or age = Unchecked.defaultof<_>;
            animal = "dog"; // or animal = Unchecked.defaultof<_>;
        }

    new (data:PetData) =
        {
            name = data.name;
            age = data.age;
            animal = data.animal;
        }
```

F# has its own style which looks like this.

```
type Pet(name:string, age:int, animal:string) =
    let mutable age = age
    let mutable animal = animal

    new (name:string) =
        Pet(name, 5, "dog")

    new (data:PetData) =
        Pet(data.name, data.age, data.animal)
```

**Edit**

Added an event used in `do` per comment request.

```
type Pet(name:string, age:int, animal:string, start:IEvent<string>) =
    let mutable age = age
    let mutable animal = animal

    // all three constructors will call this code.
    do  start.Add (fun _ -> printf "Pet was started")

    new (name:string, start:IEvent<_>) =
        // an example of different logic per constructor
        // this is called before the `do` code.
        let e = start |> Event.map (fun x -> x + " from 'name constructor'")
        Pet(name, 5, "dog", e)

    new (data:PetData, start:IEvent<_>) =
        Pet(data.name, data.age, data.animal, start)
```

Comment: That first one works; turns out it was complaining about the `[<DefaultValue>]`. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I was considering the second one, but as far as I can tell, you would end up with a duplicate of each field -- which wouldn't be good with a large number of objects.

Comment: Wait, nope, that doesn't work either -- if say one of the constructor arguments is an event that I want to bind to in a `do` clause, I can't do that because you can't have anything after the assignment in the `new()` method.

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka, you can use do.  It has to go before the additional constructors.

Comment: That works when you use `let` bindings rather than `val`, but again, that way of doing it means that all the data is duplicated in each class.

Comment: Interesting, it actually doesn't. Upon inspecting in Reflector, it turns out that any constructor parameter not used elsewhere in the type is not made into a field. So this works.

Answer (score 1):

Let bindings in a type are private and there's not much you could do about that. As such you cannot use Named Arguments. By creating properties you can do it like so, but not from inside the Pet type:

```
type Pet (name:string) =
    let mutable age = 5
    let mutable animal = "dog"

    member x.Age with get () = age and set v = age <- v
    member x.Animal with get () = animal and set v = animal <- v

type PetData = {
    name : string
    age : int
    animal : string
}
with
    member x.ToPet =
        new Pet (x.name, Age = x.age, Animal = x.animal)
```

The other option would be to create a more general constructor like Gradbot suggested, either accepting a PetData object directly or all three parameters.

Comment: `PetData` needs to be declared before `Pet`.

Comment: In my example there's no dependencies from Pet on PetData. You create an instance of Pet by calling ToPet on a PetData instance.

Comment: Yeah, but there are other things in my code that depend on PetData, which come before Pet.

Comment: You can make both types mutually dependent by declaring the second type with the ``and`` keyword rather than ``type``.

Comment: Within one file, yeah, but my `Pet` type is way down the line -- ideally in a different assembly, even.